# undefined method `relationships_path' in rails 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have the following:

Routes:

```
.
.
.
resources :users do
  resources :relationships
end
```

new.html.erb:

```
<section id="main">

  <%= form_for @relationship do |f| %> #This is the line the error is on
    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :name %>
      <%= f.text_field :name %>
    </div>
   <div class="actions"><%= f.submit %></div>
   <% end %>
</section>
```

relationships_controller.rb

```
class RelationshipsController < ApplicationController

  def new
      @id = params[:user_id]
      @rel_user = User.find_by_id(params[:user_id])
      @relationship = Relationship.new
  end

  def create

  end

end
```

relationship.rb #model

```
class Relationship < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user

    # TYPES = ['Family', 'Friend', 'Spouse']
end
```

I've hunted around on Stack Overflow and can't seem to find the answer, although, I think it has something to do with nesting my resources. I get the following error:

`undefined method 'relationships_path' for #<#<Class:0x007ff45f15ff80>:0x007ff45f15bc78>`

Any ideas?

Comment: you've nested the `relationship` ressources so the path change. As per your previous question, run `rake routes` to get the solution.

Comment: @apneadiving so I see I need to use: new_user_relationship but isn't the issue with this line: `@relationship = Relationship.new` in my controller? What am I missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should understand that all '_path' helpers generated from **route.rb** file. So in your case **route** will generate this helper **users_relationship_path** for show action.

But in your form you're using just **form_for @relationship** which is expected to use **relationship_path** helper.

So you should tell your form helper to use nesting, like this:

```
<%= form_for [@rel_user, @relationship]  do |f| %>
```

Comment: I made users plural because everything else was, but are you saying that if a user has many relationships then it should be singular?

Comment: It depends on how many users you have, maybe you're right so I fixed my answer.

Comment: Do you just need an instance of user and relationship to pass into the form? Or why do I use @rel_user and not @current_user? I've tested them and they both seem to work.

Comment: @NoahClark: There's no reason to use one or the other. All that is required for the first element in that array is an object that is of the `User` class. The second object has to be an object of the `Relationship` class.

Comment: @NoahClark, I get '@rel_user' from your code, you better know what is a user. As I understood you have several users and for every of them you want to have the relationships.